# Copying multiple selections

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a project where I need to copy some odd shapes to a specific range so the top right corners line up. The problem is that coping doesn't work on multiple selection and I can't use one select. I need a function that given range made up of multiple ranges (using union function) will copy it to the second range that is only one cell so the top right corner of first range is the second argument. Sorry for messy explanation. The example will explain it better:

```
Set my_rng1 = Union(Range("A4:C4"), Range("C2:C3"))  
Set rngDestination = Range("M2")  
call Multiple_selection_copy(my_rng1, rngDestination)
```

I would get:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPt28.png)

Of course i need the function to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only necessary to `.Offset` the given destination cell according to each source cell during a cell-by-cell-copy. This works even if the top cells are not aligned.

```
Private Sub CopyMultiRange(ByRef src As Range, ByRef dest As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    Dim topcell As Range

    Set topcell = src(1)  ' find the top right cell of source range
    For Each c In src
        If c.Row < topcell.Row Then Set topcell = c
        If c.Column > topcell.Column And c.Row = topcell.Row Then Set topcell = c
    Next c

    For Each c In src ' assign each cell's value
        dest.Offset(c.Row - topcell.Row, c.Column - topcell.Column).Value = c.Value
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. That work great. In my project I'm actually using background color but it's easy to change. Again thank you.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyMultipleSelection()
Dim my_Rng1 As Range, rngDestination As Range
Set my_Rng1 = Union(Range("C2:C3"), Range("A4:C4"))
Set rngDestination = Range("M2")
'Set my_Rng1 = Union(Range("M2:M3"), Range("K4:M4"))
'Set rngDestination = Range("A2")
Call Multiple_selection_copy(my_Rng1, rngDestination)
End Sub

Sub Multiple_selection_copy(rngSource As Range, rngDestination As Range)
Dim rowOffset As Long, colOffset As Long
Dim actCellAtStart As Range
Dim actCell As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set actCellAtStart = ActiveCell
    Debug.Print rngSource.Cells(1, 1).Address
    Debug.Print rngDestination.Cells(1, 1).Address
    colOffset = rngDestination.Cells(1, 1).Column - rngSource.Cells(1, 1).Column
    rowOffset = rngDestination.Cells(1, 1).Row - rngSource.Cells(1, 1).Row
    Debug.Print "rowOffset : "; rowOffset
    Debug.Print "colOffset : "; colOffset
    For Each actCell In rngSource.Cells
        On Error Resume Next
        Debug.Print actCell.Address; " --> "; actCell.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Address
        actCell.Copy
        actCell.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next actCell
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    actCellAtStart.Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution.